# Importing German values in openerp 7

Tags: import, odoo

I would like to import German language values in Openerp 7. Currently, the import fails due to special characters. Importing English text works perfectly.

Some of the sample values are:

- **beschränkt**
- **öffentlich nach Einzelgewerken**

Do I need to change the language preference to German first, before importing?
Also, do I need to know German to accomplish this task?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language of your User account to German is only useful if you'd like to load the German version of translatable fields. For example, if you were importing a list of Products as a CSV file, it would allow you to load the German translation of the product names. If you don't, the names will simply be stored as the master translation (English).

However it is very likely that your import fails due to encoding issue. Encoding comes into the picture because of German special characters, such as Umlauts. In that case you basically need to make sure that you are importing the CSV file using the same **Encoding** setting that was used to **export** it.

If your CSV was produced on Windows using Excel or something similar, there is a good chance it was produced with `Windows-1252` encoding. By default OpenERP will select `utf-8`, so you will need to change that in the *Encoding* selection box of the *File Format Options* that appear after you select the CSV file to import (in OpenERP 7.0).